# Selenium web driver Firefox opening blank page

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to ask something about Selenium library in Python.

I'm trying to open a webpage, directly log onto it, and access another webpage behind it (I wanted to navigate on the website after the login) with a Python script. I've found the following code on the Internet but I have a problem with the line:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

It just opens a blank page in Firefox and it looks like the script get stuck with it and does nothing afterwards. I tried in the Python interpreter and it's the same, it opens a blank page in Firefox and I lose the hand (I can't enter other commands).

python interpreter blocked:
[image]

I'm using Selenium-3.3.1 and I work under CentOS 6.5.

Is it normal? Am I missing something obvious?

Here is my code:

```
#!usr/bash/python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def loadedPage(browser):
    return browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

browser = webdriver.Firefox() #supposedly just a firefox webdrive instance creation

browser.get("http://machine/machineDir/index.php")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(loadedPage)

username=browser.find_element_by_id("username")
username.send_keys("userTest")

passwd=browser.find_element_by_id("password")
passwd.send_keys("userTestpass")
passwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: which version FF do you use?
Are you sure that your URL is correct? Did you tried with another one URL?

Comment: Same issue is getting replicated with `Selenium 3.0` with `firefox` `firefox version as = 52.0.1`

Comment: Error showing as `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:`

Comment: @nick_gabpe Yes the URL is correct, and I'm using an old version a firefox ( 17.1.10 ) which is a standardized in my company.
The problem occur even in the python interpreter whereas I didn't specified the URL yet with `browser.get("url")`

Comment: Generally if the browser opens and nothing else happens, it's a case of mismatched browser and driver versions. If you have to use a certain FF version, you'll have to look up which version of Selenium matches up with it and use that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the right version of Selenium for my old Firefox.

- Firefox version: 17.0.10
- Selenium version installed: 2.40

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `selenium 3`, `firefox` browser can't be instantiate directly, you need to configure gecko driver for the same.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: Even if the path was correct the driver is available on that path it's not getting resolved. `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: Error showing as `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:`

Comment: Excuse my noobism but isn't it a JavaScript code line ? I'm using python so i can't use it in my programm

Comment: @jainishkapadia  Please user firefox version 51 or below for selenium 3.0 , Firefox 52 supported by current version of selenium (3.3)

Comment: Yes, Now it is working for me. I have update the `selenium java jar file`
If you want to run your automation script with `firefox browser`, please `update firefox browser, Selenium java jar files, update the gecko driver as well.`